# React js - Updating state with array values and a line break

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array which is holding some errors "var HoldErrors". I am updating state in my React JS app:

```
this.setState({
   message: HoldErrors
});
```

When output on screen, this array has become a string of error messages I am displaying to the end user which is great. But how do I separate each error message in state with a line-break?

For example, when I am building my array, I am trying to add a "br" tag after each item:

```
var HoldErrors = [];
Object.keys(data.errors).forEach(function(key){
    HoldErrors.push(data.errors[key].msg + '<br>');
});
```

Obviously the "br" tag does not work in React like this.
So how can I put each error in the array on it's own line, when I am updating state? Cheers.

Edit: This is how I am rendering my component:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="Register">
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.RegisterSubmit}>
                    <input type="email" ref="email" placeholder="Email address" />
                    <input type="text" ref="name" placeholder="Your name" />
                    <input type="password" ref="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input type="password" ref="passwordc" placeholder="Confirm password" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                </form>
                <div className="validation-msg">{this.state.message}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: a <br> in jsx should be closed -> <br />

Comment: Can you show how you render your component?

Comment: I have tried a comma, and I have also tried closing the tag. This HTML is in the array which I am using to update state. All it does is print the <br /> tag out after each error, but it does not render as proper html in the page. I gather I cannot include HTML inside setState?

Comment: I m pretty sure you cant, what you can do is iterate over your error array in your render method

Comment: I just updated my question with the render function I am using. Hmm ok I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say

```
<div className="validation-msg">{this.state.message}</div>
```

the `{this.state.message}` part will be rendered by coercing it to a string (all text in the DOM ends up as a string).

Because `message` is an array, coercing it to a string is the same as joining all the elements it contains by coercing them individually to a string (in this case they are already strings) and adding a comma in between:

```js
console.log(
 ['a', 'b','c'].toString() // logs: a,b,c
)
```

What you want to do is map over this array and convert each string into a [block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) itself, like a `<div>`:

```
<div className="validation-msg">
  {this.state.message.map((m, i) => <div key={`message-${i}`}>m</div>)}
</div>
```

or an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) such as `<span>` with a `<br />` after each string

```
<div className="validation-msg">
  {this.state.message.map((m, i) => <span key={`message-${i}`}>m<br /></span>)}
</div>
```

Note: Don't forget to add [keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to your array elements.

Comment: The `<br />` has to go inside the `<span>`.

Comment: with this method if this.state.message doenst exist or is empty and the div has some css properties then the div will be displayed without anything inside

Comment: @kikiwie so? :) The OP can add a conditional rendering check for this perhaps if that is needed but that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much nem035, and also everyone else for chiming in. This is most definitely the correct approach, and worked right off the bat for me. I understand how this works and I will need to continue my reading on React Docs. Thanks again your for answer, appreciated!

Comment: I believe. your second example has two errors, shouldn't it be: `{this.state.messages.map((m, i) => <span key={`message-${i}`}>{m}<br /></span>)}`

Comment: @Patric yup, you're right, it was a copy-pasta error, fixing now

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is if `this.state.message` is an array:

```
{
     this.state.message.map((el, index) => {
          <div className={validation-msg} key={index}>{el} <br /></div>
     })
}
```

If you have something like message doesn't exist or things like that then you should:

```
{this.state.message && this.state.message.map...}
```

in your render method.

Comment: Don't you mean `<br />`?

Comment: The `<br/>` must go inside the `<div>`, and the `<div>` needs a `key` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to set html. [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
<div className="validation-msg" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.message}}></div>
```

But a better option would be to store data in state and map it to html inside `render` function.

Comment: They didn't name that attr this way by accident. You shouldn't propose to use it.

Comment: @Kinduser I named it as an option. And said there is a better one.

Comment: I agree it is not the best pattern to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, however it is perfectly valid as of right now

Comment: @AGE I guess peps got confused by word "dangerously" :) They think wow "dangerous" not just "you should trust the source"

Answer (score 0):

You are better off creating a helper function that will render each error message for you like so:

```
generateError(errorMessage, key) {
  return(
    <div className="validation-msg" key={`error-${key}`}>{errorMessage}</div>
  );
}
```

This helper function you can use it to both test your code, and modify it separately in the future without it affecting your core code structure.

In your component you can use such helper function by wrapping it within a `map` that will grab each element in the messages array and feed it to your helper function:

```
<div className="validation-msg">
{ 
  this.state.message && this.state.message.length > 0 ? this.state.message.map((msg, key) => {
    return this.generateError(msg, key);
  }) : null;
}
</div>
```

Comment: If this.state.message is empty or doesnt exist and if this div has css properties such as width , height or whatever, then the div will be displayed without any error message

Comment: @kikiwie good point, the empty array validation is quite simple, but regarding the properties in the div itself that is easily fixed via ensuring proper CSS or using a `span`, that is the OP's decision however